# read rdf file online using JENA

Tags: java, rdf, jena, semantic-web, linkedmdb

i have written this code for reading and rdf file online. but it doesn't work

```
final String uri = "http://data.linkedmdb.org/page/film/1437";
final Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
model.read(uri);
model.write(System.out);
```

Any help please?

Comment: How does it not work?  Please post details about what's going wrong -- a compiler message?  An Exception stack trace?  Wrong output?

Comment: Did you make any progress on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Your URI does not point to a RDF resource, it's a HTML web page. Try to use `http://data.linkedmdb.org/data/film/1437` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am not finding any error in the above code try with some other URI if that is working then the problem is with the URI try with the URI: http://www.ivan-herman.net/foaf.rdf this is one of the random URI I found on-line working try with it. Or may be you are not explicitly specifying the rdf filename may be that.